# How do I hover with text over div img?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how to show text in a `div` on top of an `img`? I don't want to use background images because my divs are named the same and will eventually be looped so I would like to leave it open to echo the text from a database.

So, is there a way to create a unique hover with text per `.box`? `.box` is repeated numerous times. Can I do it through CSS or jQuery?

Let me know if this makes sense or you need more information.

Thanks,
Katie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an absolutely positioned div that is a child of the div with the image in it.
Example:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <img src='yourImage.jpg' alt='image'/>
  <div class='child'>
    <p>your text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
.parent
{
    position:relative;
}
.child
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    padding:10px;

    display:none;
}
```

hope this helps

EDIT: OOPS! misread the question.
To acheive the hover, just add display:none; to #child and use this jQuery to show it on hover:

```
$(function(){
    $('.parent').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('.child').fadeIn();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('.child').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

EDIT #2: changed everything to classes so you can have any number of them

EDIT #3: this is becoming a habit :) fixed some spelling and css

EDIT #4: as per kokos' comment, the hover can be done in pure css (but without the nice fadyness of jquery)

Comment: How about the function '.hover(over, out)'? I think it does the same.

Comment: You can do the hover with css as well: `.parent:hover .child { display:block; }`.

Comment: both correct, i prefer to use mouseleave and mouseenter though because it's a little clearer in the code what each handler is and what it is doing

Comment: @jammypeach - Keep in mind that `hover` works slightly differently from `mouseenter/leave`.

Comment: @christian: yeah i know mouseenter/leave will trigger under slightly different circumstances. now i'm thinking about it, this particular application might suit hover better - but for the purposes of this example, the principle remains the same

Comment: this has a problem that you will need to specifically set the parent's width, as it will stretch with browser resize/grandparent container resize

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I did it through CSS only. I've been using CSS3 transitions so the fading fanciness will be through that in which I would use hover. Before my site goes live I'll have to back and write the fixes for browsers that don't understand the CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

See a correct (pure css) implementation at:

http://jsfiddle.net/rs9Vz/

here is the code

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://colorvisiontesting.com/plate%20with%205.jpg"/>
  <div class="child"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.child{
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    left:0; bottom: 0;
    color:white;padding:10px;
    display:none;
}

.container{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.container:hover .child{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want any image on your page to have a caption to do this I suggest using jquery to check which images you want a caption for and then displaying or hiding the caption.

```
$(".imgCon>img").each(function() {
    $(this).hover(

    function() {
        $(this).parent().find("span").toggleClass("captionShow");
    });
});
```

This would check each image that is in an image container and then display the caption when the image is hovered.

Assuming your html is structured like this:

```
<div class="imgCon">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="#" alt="Image"/>
    <span class="captionHide">Some caption text</span>
</div>
<div class="imgCon">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="#" alt="Image"/>
    <span class="captionHide">Some caption text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.captionHide
{
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.captionShow
{
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3BF2H/15/

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute may be all you need. Set it on the div or image and the browser will automatically display it when you hover with the mouse. MrBorna's solution is better if you need/want more control over the text display format. For a description search for 'DOM title attribute' or 'tooltip' e.g. : http://javascript.about.com/library/bltip1.htm